# Pushing to state array in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

I have my code where I assign an onPress event the following function (please mind the annotation):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
state = {
  noteArray: [],
  noteText: "",
};
constructor(props: any) {
  super(props);
}
addNote() {
  if (this.state.noteText) {
    var d = new Date();
    let noteArray = [...this.state.noteArray];
    noteArray.push({
    date: d.getFullYear() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate(),
        note: this.state.noteText,
      });
    //If I place a "console.log(noteArray); return;" here I get the object I expect.
    this.setState({ noteArray });
    //If I set the same "console.log" here I will get an empty array in console (because the "valuated just now" but if I do console.log(noteArray[0]) I get the correct object)
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I havent been able to modify the variable "this.state.noteArray". If I console.log the variable in the end, I always end with an empty array. Here is the object that's calling it:

```
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.addButton}
          onPress={this.addNote.bind(this)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.addButotnText}>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

And I also have another object modifying the state, but this is successfuly doing it:

```
     <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        placeholderTextColor="white"
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        placeholder=">Note"
        value={this.state.noteText}
        onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({ noteText })}
      ></TextInput>
```

Thank you for your kind insight

Comment: In the future try to include the language tag or specify the language in your markup otherwise the syntax highlighting won't work. I added the Javascript tag for you.

Comment: @LuisE It's working fine seem to

Answer (score -3):

I think this is probably because you are not using setState in the right way,
you should do :

```
this.setState({ noteArray: noteArray })
```

and not :

```
this.setState({ noteArray });
```

hope I helped you ;)

Comment: those are both 100% identical, there's no difference at all between the full syntax and the shortcut